# How to release a rescued European Rabbit back into the wild?

Tags: rabbits, safety, domestication

We saved a [bunny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_rabbit) from certain death and raised him from baby for 3 months.

We have to leave Morocco, and there are *no* shelters, *no* safe places for him. Basically, the choices are:

- a home where he will be, eventually, food;
- release him into the wild;
- buy another bunny and release both into the wild to keep him company.

We can't take him with us, due to import regulations.
Also, he has accustomed to us ( and we to him!).

Please advise!

Comment: well, its possible to taken him with us, but he has to be quarantined for a month and subject to tests. And once back home, we would have to release him into the wild too.

Comment: Related: [Can I make a baby wild rabbit a pet?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/854/can-i-make-a-baby-wild-rabbit-a-pet) and [Can I release my pet rabbit in the wild?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/can-i-release-my-pet-rabbit-in-the-wild).

Comment: thanks  @Zaralynda, i've searched before i posted but only found the second question, which wasn't exactly our problem. the first link, however, is priceless. Although, the question is for doing the opposite, there's a lot of relevant information for us. i'll wait a few hours more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are still unable to locate a wild animal rescue in your area that can take the young wild rabbit:

Your third option "buy another bunny and release both into the wild to keep him company." is **NOT** a viable solution. Domestic rabbits are not compatible with wild rabbits.  The question [What species of wild rabbit is the domestic house rabbit descended from?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5705) highlights they are not even able to inter breed.  Additionally making two rabbits "be friends" is called 'bonding' and it is not easy. Also the Questions that Zaralynda posted in the comments, expand on why releasing a domestic rabbit is not appropriate.

Your first option "a home where he will be, eventually, food;" is presumably about transferring ownership of the rabbit to a person who will eat him, when he grows up. Depending on the laws in your area this may be unlawfully.  Owning, selling or transferring wildlife is generally unlawful.

Your second option "release him into the wild;" is the best of the 3 options you have listed.  Rabbits are vegetarians/herbivores so complex skills are not required to find food.  As unpleasant as it is to think about [rabbits multiple fast](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/) and most wild rabbits get eaten, that is part of the circle of life. Wild rabbits have different inherent skills then domestic rabbits so there is nothing cruel or unusual about releasing them back to the wild.

A fourth option is [euthanasia](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euthanasia), which may be a more human choice, if there is not an existing wild rabbit population in your area (but presumably there is as you found him in the wild).  Also the veterinarians in your area capable of performing the task, may be legally prohibited from euthanizing a wild rabbit.

Given the situation you are in, and if you were my neighbor I would suggest releasing him into the wild as close to where you found him as possible.

Comment: hi! its been a while, and i miss our bunny so much. in the end we did release him in a wooded mountain. hope he lived happily ever after