# My rabbit's hair looks wet and dirty and it’s getting worse

Tags: health, rabbits, diseases, skin-condition, infections

I recently bought a rabbit from pet store and it's been a week that my rabbit hair has changed. It looks like the hair around the mouth, nose and stomach is dirty and wet and it's not getting better. It is just increasing every day, it's making my rabbit really tired and it also smells bad. I feel like it's an infection.

[image]

I also have chickens in the yard and sometimes I let my rabbit play in the yard.

He always trying to clean himself and he shakes his body a lot.
I have two more rabbits and I don’t know whether I should put them together or not because maybe it could transfer to other rabbits.
Sometimes I feel it’s only dirty and I have to wash it, but I don’t know if it's safe to wash him or not.

I want to know what is this and how I can treat it.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. If you think your rabbit may have an infection or be otherwise ill, please don't wait for strangers on the internet, but ask a local vet or maybe another rabbit breeder for help.

Comment: Yeah right I can’t wait anymore thank u

Comment: When you know what's going on, you can post an answer to your own question here. That way you can help other people who have the same problem. You can also earn reputation points for your answer.

Comment: Do you see injury of the skin in the dirty/wet area of the fur? Do you see more than normal amount of liquid at the nose or mouth? It is possible to clean the rabbits fur with a washcloth and warm water (and no soap in the first try). Your rabbit seems to have a "teddy" type of fur, this lacks of the natural water-repellent surface normal fur has. This could be the cause for the extreme look, but is not the general cause of the problem.

Comment: How is the surface shaped, the rabbit pee on? I can imagine a setup, where the rabbit squirts itself because the surface is not soaking the liquid

Comment: have a look into this answer to get more advise on how to clean a rabbits fur: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5616/how-do-you-groom-an-angora-rabbit/5624#5624

Comment: After some research: Please check how your rabbit urinates. If the wet fur is caused by urine (bad smell) it could be symptom of an bladder infection or similar. First aid (waiting for the appointment at the vet) is a heat source (infrared lamp, fabric covered plastic bottle with warm water) and a lots of water (water bowl instead of bottle, strong diluted vegetable juices, fresh greens like cucumber and leaves) and high hygiene of the litter box (more cleaning, important rabbit sit in a dry place)

Comment: Thank u for your advice, we went to the vet it was infection, doctor did some injections but my rabbit died

Comment: I am sorry to read this. It is hard, if a new friend goes this quick. For your second rabbit. now left alone, you need to find a new friend in near future. Single rabbits are not happy and because of this get ill more often than rabbits with a rabbit friend.

Comment: I apologies for the late reply, if you write @Allerleirauh in your message next time, then I will get a message, that there is a comment for me.